# proof of limit involving convergent sequence

Tags: analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

Let (a$_n$)$_{n \in N}$  be a convergent sequence in **R** with the limit a $\in$ **R**.

Furthermore, let  y$_n$ = $\frac 1n$$\sum_{i=1}^n$a$_n$.

Show that $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}$ y$_n$ = a.

--

I thought that $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}$ y$_n$ = 0 because $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}$ $\frac 1n$ = 0, and I could apply the formulae for convergent sequences, but I guess I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Take any $\varepsilon >0$ and let $k_0$ be such that for all $k\geqslant k_0$ we have $$|a_k -g|\leqslant \varepsilon$$
then
$$\left|\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n a_k -g \right|\leqslant \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{k_0 -1} |a_j -g| + \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=k_0}^{n} |a_j -g|\leqslant \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{k_0 -1} |a_j -g| +\frac{n-k_0 +1}{n} \varepsilon \leq 2\varepsilon$$
for sufficiently large $n.$